# Absolute timestamps from the sender report (SR) for RTSP video stream

Tags: python, timestamp, sender

I get video streams from ip cameras using rtsp in python and want to get absolute timestamp for each frame in the sender reports. If I read a stream the camtime obviously starts from zero:
ret, image_np = cap.read()
camtime = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)/1000.
I need to know when the frames are recorded since the cameras are located in different time zones and the frames are received with different delays. Can someone advise what library to use and how the python code should look like?
Thanks!
P.S. I can get camera streaming start time from ffmpeg in SDP (option "o").

Comment: "*the camtime obviously starts from zero*" - so you will also need a reference point in time, i.e. when the recording started. do you have that? In principle, `time` and `datetime` from the standard lib would be your way to go. And make sure to map all times to UTC as early as possible - otherwise, this will be a pain ;-)

Comment: hi MrFuppes, thanks but I don't think it answers my question. The timestamp of the frame created by the camera might be quite different from time of its processing e.g. due to network delay

Comment: so you only have the timestamp of the moment you *receive* the frame? sounds like this is more about determining the network delay; maybe you should clarify that in the question.

Comment: I refer to RTSP document (https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326) and my understanding is that NTP timestamps (wall clock) available via RTCP is what is required. This NTP timestamp should be available from the protocol header.

Answer (score 4):

After a solid three weeks of experimenting I managed to do this with GStreamer.

GStreamer applications are made up of pipelines of elements where each element has different uses and processes the data flow differently. Read the documentation to get a grasp on what is happening and [this tutorial](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/concepts.html?gi-language=python). In short, data is passed from element to element within buffers and is processed accordingly before passed to the next element.

When you understand how GStreamer works, setup a pipeline like this:

`rtspsrc -> rtph264depay -> h264parse -> avdec_h264 -> videoconvert -> capsfilter -> videoconvert -> fakesink`

It is a matter of learning each element's properties to set up your pipeline correctly but the most significant thing here is to set up your `rtspsrc` correctly:

```
rtsp_source = Gst.ElementFactory.make("rtsprc", "rtsp_source")
rtsp_source.set_property("location", RTSP_URL)
```

Then get the `sink` pad of your `rtph264depay` which has the RTP data and setup a probe for it:

```
pad = element.get_static_pad("sink")
pad.add_probe(Gst.PadProbeType.BUFFER, callback_func, None)
```

This means that whenever data passes this pad, a callback function is called which receives the data in a `buffer`. Access the buffer:

```
r, map_info = buffer.map(Gst.MapFlags.READ)
raw_data = map_info.data
buffer.unmap(map_info)
```

Now you have the RTP packet with it's header and payload in `raw_data`. From it, you can now extract the RTP timestamp within your callback. You can either do it yourself, or even better, I preferred to do it with [this amazing library](https://dpkt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/dpkt/rtp.html).

Then, if you also need the frame, setup another probe in your `fakesink`'s `sink` pad. In the same way, your buffer `map_info` now has frame data which you can convert to a frame with `numpy` for example:

```
rgb_frame = np.ndarray(
            shape=(height, width, 3),
            dtype=np.uint8,
            buffer=map_info.data,
        )
```

Do what you will with the frame and timestamp. Good luck!

Comment: could you maybe share a working code example? I almost got it working but it would be very much appreciated!