# Gstreamer -- get camera timestamp of the frame . Need some instructions with C# code

Tags: c#, gstreamer, gstreamer-sharp

Given following pipeline *"rtspsrc ! decodebin ! jpegenc ! appsink"* (code on C# below).
**How can I get camera timestamp (I mean real(or physical) camera time,  when the camera itself captured the image, not pts or dts)?** I'm not very familiar with this domain or gstreamer, just started to learn. Also I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73255066/241446) answer, it is very helpful, at least I got some keywords to look for( RTCPBuffer, RTCPPacket) but still I don't know how to do this with gstreamer-sharp lib. In code below I use appsink, so I hope to get data(needed ts) from NewSample event handler.

Here is code:

```
private static Pipeline BuildRtspPipe()
{
    // Build the pipeline
    var rtspSrc = ElementFactory.Make("rtspsrc", "rtspsrc");
    rtspSrc["location"] = "rtsp://someaddr";


    var dec = ElementFactory.Make("decodebin", "decodebin");

    var jpegenc = ElementFactory.Make("jpegenc", "jpegenc");


    var appSink = new AppSink("");
    appSink.NewSample += AppSink_NewSample;
    appSink.EmitSignals = true;
    
    var pipeline = new Pipeline("test");

    pipeline.Add(rtspSrc, dec, jpegenc, appSink);



    if ( !rtspSrc.Link(dec) )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not link pipeline elements");
    }

    rtspSrc.PadAdded += (o, args) =>
    {
        var decpad = dec.GetStaticPad("sink");
        if (decpad.IsLinked)
        {
            return;
        }

        args.NewPad.Link(decpad);
    };

    dec.PadAdded += (o, args) =>
    {
        var jpegencpad = jpegenc.GetStaticPad("sink");
        if (jpegencpad.IsLinked)
        {
            return;
        }
        
        var caps = args.NewPad.QueryCaps();
        if (caps == null)
            return;



        args.NewPad.Link(jpegencpad);
    };

    if (!Element.Link(jpegenc, appSink))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Could not link pipeline elements");
        throw new Exception();
    }

    return pipeline;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that answer to my question is here -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75799182/241446

Need add probe to sink buffer, like

```
 foreach (Pad pad in splitmuxsink.Pads)
        {
            
            if (pad.Direction == PadDirection.Sink)
            {
                pad.AddProbe(PadProbeType.Buffer, (pad, probeInfo) =>
                {
                    var buf = probeInfo.Buffer;
                    var metaTs = buf.GetReferenceTimestampMeta();
                    if (metaTs.Timestamp > 0)
                    {
                    
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"probe counter: {probeCounter}");
                    
                    }
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"splitmuxsink element, buffer ts: {metaTs.Timestamp}");
                    
                    return PadProbeReturn.Ok;
                });
            }
        }
```

Btw, there is [thread](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2023-July/081503.html) with more details, especially with network part --https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/gstreamer-devel/2023-July/081546.html